# Tengo nvim 0.8 instalado pero me inicia nvim 0.7

Tags: linux, terminal, kali-linux, zsh, nvim

Tengo instalado la version de neovim 0.8 pero cuando inicio neovim me sale que tengo la version 0.7 que es lo que podria fallar?

Comment: por favor lee [Como elaborar una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y tambien [ejemplo minimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que no recibas votos negativos e intenten cerrar por ser [chat gpt](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)